# php search results need be show when I click back

Tags: php, mysql

I just finished  products website.There is a search form in the website.
 Search result are working fine.when I click on the result item that retrieving based on ID on the next page.

The problem is that When click back I need to search same keyword to get the result list. Is there any solution to show results on that page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most compatible is to use the search term as an `$_GET`-variable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use sessions ( http://php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php ). There are 2 ways to do it.

1. Have in your session your search results. So for example will be something like this:

```
$_SESSION['destination'] = $_POST['destination'];
$_SESSION['ID'] = $_POST['result_id'];
```

1. You can have to your session only the ID and then in this id to have your data serialized ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php ) . The when you want to export your search again you simply unserialize ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php ). So it will be:

```
$_SESSION[$my_id] = serialize($_POST);
```

and to get the data

```
$data = unserialize($_SESSION[$my_id]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have your search form do a GET instead of a POST, that way what was searched for is retained by the browser.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure at what level you are at, but have you thought about caching? You can use  [Memcaching](http://php.net/memcache) which would allow you to cache the previous page.

You could also change your query from a POST to a GET like mlaw just mentioned.

You can even use Sessions to keep the results valid. [Sessions](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) can be found here

Comment: I think there is no simple solution with $_POST method
I just changed all the code to $_GET method 
I'm happy for ur adive

Answer (score 0):

Conceivably, you could save the POST of the search to a variable, pass it forward when you click on the product, then, if you click a link that takes you back, send that information as  a new POST. Still wouldn't affect the browser's back button usage, but if you're looking for a programmatic answer, there's one.